# UIPickerView crashes when scrolling 2 components together

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, uipickerview, nszombies

Actually, I asked a same question before, but I have not found a way to fix it yet, so here I comes again.

My situation:

I have a `UIPickerView` with 2 related components, and the number and content of the rows in the 2nd or right components changes with the currently selected row in the 1st or left component, which is a quite common and useful function of `UIPickerView`.

Now, if I use 2 thumbs to scroll both components together, my app gets crashed very easily and soon with the information below:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception of class '_NSZombie_NSException'
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

The ironic thing is that, I can't debug it.

Actually, if I add a break point in the `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent` method, I can't even scroll both components quickly together since it would stop at the break point every time I just put my finger on the screen.

I can only guess the reason is that when the 1st component is being scrolled, the supposed number of rows in 2nd component keeps changing, but meantime, the `UIPickerView` is asking for the title and number for the 2nd component, then it crashes.

But I haven't found any method that can be used to judge whether a component is being scrolled. So I can't find the correct time to reject the request of the `pickerView`'s `delegate` and `dataSource` for the 2nd component.

Did anyone meet similar situation?

Thanks for your help! I'd appreciate it a lot!

---

In my code, the bug is about the `typePicker`, so I deleted all other codes that is not related to `typePicker`.

Here, `type` and `detailTypes` are two entities in Core Data, and a to-many relationship called `details` reaches from `type` to `detailsTypes`.

If the type is "Nations", for example, the `detailTypes` would be "the U.S.", "France", "China", and so on.

So in the `typePicker`, the 1st or left components show all type entities, and the 2nd or right components show the corresponding `detailTypes` entities according to the currently selected type in 1st component.

And the 1st row of both components in `typePicker` is always "None", to allow users not to select a specific type, which is why there is many "+1" in the code.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
if (pickerView == self.typePicker)
        return 2;
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSUInteger majorTypeRow = [self.typePicker selectedRowInComponent:0] - 1;
    if (pickerView == self.typePicker) {
        if (component == 0)
            return [self.types count] + 1;
        else {
            if (majorTypeRow == -1) // no major type entities
                return 1;
            NSString *majorTypeName = [[self.types objectAtIndex:majorTypeRow] name];
            NSArray *detailType = [self.detailTypes objectForKey:majorTypeName];
            if (detailType) 
                return [detailType count] + 1;
            else {
                NSManagedObject *majorType = [self.types objectAtIndex:majorTypeRow];
                NSSet *minorTypes = [majorType valueForKey:@"details"];
                NSSortDescriptor *sd = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"order" ascending:NO];
                NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sd, nil];
                NSArray *array = [minorTypes sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
                [self.detailTypes setObject:array forKey:majorTypeName];
                [sd release];
                return [array count] + 1;
        }
    }
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSUInteger majorTypeRow = [self.typePicker selectedRowInComponent:0] - 1;
    row--;
    if (pickerView == self.typePicker) {
        if (component == 0)
            [pickerView reloadComponent:1]; // I believe this is where the bug starts, but I can't find the exact line of code that causes the crash
        else {
            if (row == -1)
                self._detailType = nil;
            else {
                NSString *majorTypeName = [[self.types objectAtIndex:majorTypeRow] name];
                NSArray *dt = [self.detailTypes objectForKey:majorTypeName];
                if (dt)
                    self._detailType = [dt objectAtIndex:row];
            }
        }
    }
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:path animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}
```

Comment: If a question is not getting attention you need to start bounty for it. Can you show your implementation of UIPicker delegates?

Comment: Sure I can, but it is a lot of code in these methods since the logic is kind of complicated, I'm afraid a bunch of strange code would scare people away,,,=.= Do I really need to?

Comment: Make sure that your dataSource always have valid Data and you are not missing any special conditions in your logic. Showing your code can avoid many wild guesses.

Comment: @Anupdas thanks for your reminding! I've added my code in the question! Please take a look!

Comment: I have worked out a demo for you. Please check if that what you want and compare it with yours. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35012982/Demo%20Projects/TestMultiPickerView.zip

Comment: Why don't you disallow touch on the dependent picker when user is interacting with the primary picker?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The crash is due to this line in your delegates

```
NSUInteger majorTypeRow = [self.typePicker selectedRowInComponent:0] - 1;
```

As other pointed out by others you need to keep two seperate arrays or objects which can provide the dataSource for the respective components.

You have a majorType and detailType. You can have an array of `majorTypes` and a `selectedMajorType`. Keeping an extra selectedMajorType removes the need to use the `selectedRowInComponent:` and no longer crashes the app.

```
#pragma mark - UIPickerViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSInteger rows = 0;
    if (component) {
         rows = [self.selectedMajorType.minorTypes count];
    }else{
        rows = [self.majorTypes count];
    }
    return rows+1;
}
```

UIPickerViewDelegate implementation

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
             titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
            forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    row--;
    NSString *title = @"None";
    if (component) {
        NSArray *minorTypes = [self.selectedMajorType.minorTypes allObjects];
        if (row >= 0 && row < [minorTypes count]) {
            MinorType *minorType = minorTypes[row];
            title = minorType.name;
        }
    }else{
        if(row>=0 && row < [self.majorTypes count]){
            MajorType *majorType = self.majorTypes[row];
            title =  majorType.name;
        }
    }
    return title;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
      didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
       inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    row--;
    if (component==0) {
        if (row >= 0 && row < [self.majorTypes count]) {
             self.selectedMajorType = self.majorTypes[row];
        }else {
           self.selectedMajorType = nil;
        }

        [pickerView reloadComponent:1];
    }
}
```

[Demo Source Code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35012982/Demo%20Projects/TestMultiPickerView_V2.0.zip)

Comment: Thanks, this seems nice, I'm going to try it today.

Comment: Thanks man, it turned out that there were at least 3 bugs in these code that caused the crash, and one of them was what you pointed out. Beginning with your help, I think I've fixed them all! lol

Comment: @Eno It's a pleasure. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I understand the problem:

The problem with scrolling two components together is that as your UIPickerView data source may be changing due to dependecies you've created with the data relationships. I think you need to create two arrays that represent the left and right respectively and repopulate based on which component you change!

The solution can be found by checking out a similar problem here! [UIPickerView with two components crashes when scrolling both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601144/uipickerview-with-two-components-crashes-when-scrolling-both)

Additionally, in regards to checking to see if your UIPickerView is scrolling, you can simply set up a timer. A helpful link is here: [Determining if UIPickerWheel is scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304839/determining-if-uipickerwheel-is-scrolling) ! By checking to see if the current rows match, you can tell (within a short interval) if the user has moved the wheel!

I hope this is clear and helpful!